# How to load vendor Rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, stylesheet

how to load tree(!) of vendor to rails 3 app ?

Now Im using this way:

```
//= require vendor ../../../vendor/assets/ {stylesheet or javascript}
```

And this won't work for me:

```
require_tree vendor OR require vendor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create files like

- `vendor/assets/javascripts/vendor.js`
- `vendor/assets/stylesheets/vendor.css`

Inside `vendor.js` you can do

```
//= require_tree .
```

and inside `vendor.css` you can do

```
/* 
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

And then inside `app/assets/javascripts/vendor.js` put

```
//= require vendor
```

and in `app/assets/stylesheets/vendor.css` put

```
/* 
 *= require vendor
 */
```

It should be noted, once you get more than a couple files you want to include, you're *very* likely better off avoiding `require_tree` and instead using a `//= require` line for **each** file independently. This lets you order your assets properly to ensure any dependencies on one another are resolved. By doing what I describe above you set yourself up for success with the individual `//= require` lines in your `vendor/` directories when that time comes.